# Java heap space memory error while while downloading JR report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am fetching data from data base (records in table 911830) and adding it to *JR* report for 1000 records its working fine. When I exceed or some time its giving Java heap space memory error as title of this issue it is related to Java heap memory, but I increase it 3Gb as (Xms3072m-Xmx3072m). But still getting same error

My system configuration is as below::

1. 64 bit is fine
2. Redhat/ CentOS (latest versions)
3. 120GB with RAID configuration
4. 2GB of RAM and a 2CPU machine

console error ::

```
Aug 26, 2012 7:11:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet `enter code here`jsp threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.util.CharArray.grow(CharArray.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.util.CharArray.append(CharArray.java:117)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.tokenizer.Parser$ReusableToken.writeTo(Parser.java:343)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.State.handleText(State.java:64)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.HTMLProcessor$2.text(HTMLProcessor.java:103)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.tokenizer.Parser.parsedText(Parser.java:295)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.tokenizer.Parser.start(Parser.java:109)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.tokenizer.TagTokenizer.start(TagTokenizer.java:33)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.HTMLProcessor.process(HTMLProcessor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.HTMLPageParser.parse(HTMLPageParser.java:52)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.PageParser2ContentProcessor.build(PageParser2ContentProcessor.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.ContentBufferingResponse.getContent(ContentBufferingResponse.java:54)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:137)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
Aug 26, 2012 7:11:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.util.CharArray.grow(CharArray.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.util.CharArray.append(CharArray.java:117)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.tokenizer.Parser$ReusableToken.writeTo(Parser.java:343)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.State.handleText(State.java:64)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.HTMLProcessor$2.text(HTMLProcessor.java:103)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.tokenizer.Parser.parsedText(Parser.java:295)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.tokenizer.Parser.start(Parser.java:109)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.tokenizer.TagTokenizer.start(TagTokenizer.java:33)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.html.HTMLProcessor.process(HTMLProcessor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.HTMLPageParser.parse(HTMLPageParser.java:52)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.PageParser2ContentProcessor.build(PageParser2ContentProcessor.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.ContentBufferingResponse.getContent(ContentBufferingResponse.java:54)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:137)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
```

Comment: I was going through your configuration & I found it odd that you are allocating 3 Gb of RAM (Xms3072m-Xmx3072m) when your physical memory is 2 GB (2GB of RAM and a 2CPU machine).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to profile your application?

Try to take a memory dump and investigate, maybe you have too many objects in memory of the same type/ some very big objects that eats all your memory.

You can consider to use JVisualVM or any other profile available at your organization

Answer (score 0):

May be easier than trying to sort the memory dump out would be to try [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu). It is pretty good in spotting memory leaks.